# Read the content of an xml file within a zip package

Tags: c#, zip

I am required to read the contents of an .xml file using the Stream (Here the xml file is existing with in the zip package). Here in the below code, I need to get the file path at runtime (here I have hardcoded the path for reference). Please let me know how to read the file path at run time.

I have tried to use string s =entry.FullName.ToString(); but get the error "Could not find the Path". I have also tried to hard code the path as shown below. however get the same FileNotFound error.

```
string metaDataContents;
using (var zipStream = new FileStream(@"C:\OB10LinuxShare\TEST1\Temp" + "\\"+zipFileName+".zip", FileMode.Open))
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Read))
{
    foreach (var entry in archive.Entries)
    {
        if (entry.Name.EndsWith(".xml"))
        {
            FileInfo metadataFileInfo = new FileInfo(entry.Name);
            string metadataFileName = metadataFileInfo.Name.Replace(metadataFileInfo.Extension, String.Empty);
            if (String.Compare(zipFileName, metadataFileName, true) == 0)
            {
                using (var stream = entry.Open())
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    metaDataContents = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    clientProcessLogWriter.WriteToLog(LogWriter.LogLevel.DEBUG, "metaDataContents : " + metaDataContents);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have also tried to get the contents of the .xml file using the Stream object as shown below. But here I get the error "Stream was not readable".

```
Stream metaDataStream = null;
string metaDataContent = string.Empty;
using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
{                                
    metaDataStream = stream;
}
using (var reader = new StreamReader(metaDataStream))
{
    metaDataContent = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Kindly suggest, how to read the contents of the xml with in a zip file using Stream and StreamReader by specifying the file path at run time

Comment: Please pay more attention to formatting when you post - both of the code snippets were fine for the first line, but everything else was indented way too far. Use the preview to make sure your post looks good before you submit it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your section code snippet is failing because when you reach the end of the first `using` statement:

```
using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
{                                
    metaDataStream = stream;
}
```

... the stream will be disposed. That's the point of a `using` statment. You should be fine with this *sort* of code, but load the XML file while the stream is open:

```
XDocument doc;
using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
{                                
    doc = XDocument.Load(stream);
}
```

That's to load it as XML... if you really just want the text, you could use:

```
string text;
using (Stream stream = entry.Open())
{                                
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        text = reader.ReadToEnd();
    }
}
```

Again, note how this is reading *before* it hits the end of either `using` statement.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was getting the error because of the stream  being disposed before I read the contents. It really worked.

Comment: Thanks Jon. I was getting the error because of the stream  being disposed before I read the contents. It really worked.

Comment: You could put the two `using`s sequentially without opening the code block after the `using (Stream stream = entry.Open())`. I believe I saw somewhere in the MSDN that it is a recommended way of utilizing the `using`s.

Comment: @hellouworld: That's an option, but I'm not sure I'd say it's recommended. As of C# 8 you can write "bare" using statements without any braces at all, that are implicitly "to the end of the current block" which would make it simpler.

Comment: Did not know about that. Thank you.

Comment: @hellouworld: And yes, it was meant to be note. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample of how to read a zip file using .net 4.5

```
private void readZipFile(String filePath)
    {
        String fileContents = "";
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.File.Exists(filePath))
            {
                System.IO.Compression.ZipArchive apcZipFile = System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.Open(filePath, System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveMode.Read);
                foreach (System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry entry in apcZipFile.Entries)
                {
                        if (entry.Name.ToUpper().EndsWith(".XML"))
                        {
                            System.IO.Compression.ZipArchiveEntry zipEntry = apcZipFile.GetEntry(entry.Name);

                            using (System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(zipEntry.Open()))
                            {
                                //read the contents into a string
                                fileContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                            }

                        }
                }


            }
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }
    }
```